# Ubuntu on VirtualBox - GParted not showing added disk space

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, virtualbox, gparted, mac

I'm running an Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox on Mac OSX

I used `VBoxManage modifyhd /path/to/vm/ --resize 40000` to add increase the space of my VM from 15GB to 40GB.  I ran the VM and installed gparted on Ubuntu.  When I open it though, the added space isn't appearing in gparted?

[image: Image of VirtualBox at 39GB]

[image: Image of GParted in Ubuntu not showing newly added space]

Comment: Did you reboot the guest system after you resized the virtual disk?

Comment: Try cloning your virtual machine and then when you view the file system with Gparted your extra storage space should appear.

Answer (score 3):

Try booting the VM to a live image containing gparted (for example [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)).  That should permit you to see the unallocated space and also to resize/move any of the partitions.

If you need more details I found the following article with screen shots on the Internet.
[Resize /dev/sda1 Disk of Your Vagrant / VirtualBox VM](https://tvi.al/tag/vm/)

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing a more complete explanation of the required steps.

Comment: I booted it with the https://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-1.4.0-5-amd64.iso and I couldn't see the the extra virtual disk space I added (to a dynamically allocated .vdi virtual hard disk with Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it).

Answer (score 2):

**You may have resized the wrong .vdi file.** I had the same problem, even though I used a bootable gparted .iso file, rather than one on the hardrive itself. I found the answer (sort of cryptically) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174571/gparted-doesnt-recognize-my-newly-resized-vdi

It might a little more sense how it applies to you if you read here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#diffimages

I had resized the .vdi file, which I wrongly assumed was the most up-to-date version of the virtual hard disk. **When I resized the "snapshot" files I was using, it fixed the problem.**[image]

As you can see here, the arrow under plainly-named .vdi file shows the "snapshots" in current use. When I boot up my virtual machine, it's labelled "LinuxLab (Snapshot 2)", because (roughly speaking) it actually uses '{809a...}.vdi' as its hard disk, not 'LinuxLab.vdi'. The file 'LinuxLab.vdi' contains the virtual hard disk as it was when I took Snapshot 1, '{7cc5...}.vdi' is a "differencing image" that describes how to turn 'LinuxLab.vdi' into the virtual hard disk as it was when I took Snapshot 2, and '{809a...}.vdi' describes how to change THAT into the virtual hard disk as it was when I last powered the system down. Thus, 'LinuxLab.vdi' is actually the backup, and '{809a...}.vdi' is actually the most recent version. **I believe it's this last file whose size actually needs to be updated, unless you plan to revert your VM to a previously taken snapshot.**

To explain the above image: previously, all three of these .vdi files had a virtual size of 10.00 GB. Then I changed LinuxLab.vdi to 16.00 GB, and gparted couldn't see the change. Then, I increased the size of both of the other snapshots to 16.00 GB and gparted could see the change when I rebooted it. *Probably*, only the virtual size of the last one actually needs to be changed, but changing the virtual size has no effect on the actual size of a dynamically allocated virtual hard disk, and the "Virtual Media Manager" doesn't let you shrink their virtual size after you've raised it, even if none of the extra space has been allocated and the VM hasn't even been booted since the change, so I figured it was more trouble than it was worth to reshrink their virtual sizes.